# Suffix Array, n^2*log(n) faster than n*log^2(n) even for large inputs?

Tags: python, algorithm, suffix-array

I learned this theory in class and decided to implement everything to make sure I understood it all; but the theoretical results don't align with the memory and time usages I obtain. I'm pretty sure this is not a shortcoming of theoretical algorithms but rather a mistake on my end and would like to investigate it.

The naive approach to constructing a suffix array is to generate all suffixes of the input string and then sort them lexicographically to obtain the final suffix array.

```py
def naive_suffix_array(text: str) -> list[int]:
    n = len(text)
    suffixes = [(text[i:], i) for i in range(n)]
    suffixes.sort()
    suffix_array = [index for _, index in suffixes]
    return suffix_array
```

This algorithm has a time complexity of `O(n^2 * log n)` since we are generating all `n` suffixes of the input string `(O(n))` and then sorting them, which takes `O(n log n) * O(n)` time (because ordering two strings of size `n` takes `O(n)`). Space complexity is `O(n^2)`.

The efficient algorithm uses a "doubling" technique that sorts the suffixes based on the first `k` characters, where `k` is doubled in each step until `k >= n`. This approach reduces the time complexity to `O(n * log(n)^2)`. Space complexity is `O(n)`.

```py
def efficient_suffix_array(text: str) -> list[int]:
    text = text + "$"  # add a special character to the end of the string
    
    n = len(text)
    k = 1

    # Initialize rank array with character values
    rank = [ord(c) for c in text]

    while k < n:
        # Sort the suffixes based on the first k characters (suffixes is a list of indices)
        suffixes = sorted(
            range(n),
            key=lambda i: (rank[i], rank[(i + k) % n])
        )
        
        # Update the rank array with new rank values
        new_rank = [0] * n
        rank_value = 0  # goes up by one when the rank changes
        prev_suffix = suffixes[0]  # the best suffix
        new_rank[prev_suffix] = rank_value  # the best suffix gets rank = 0

        for i in range(1, n):
            cur_suffix = suffixes[i]  
            if rank[cur_suffix] != rank[prev_suffix] or rank[(cur_suffix + k) % n] != rank[(prev_suffix + k) % n]:
                # if rank of first k characters are different, or they are the same but rank of next k characters are different
                rank_value += 1
            new_rank[cur_suffix] = rank_value
            prev_suffix = cur_suffix
        
        if rank_value == n - 1:
            # if all suffixes are in different equivalence classes, we are done, we don't need to look at the next characters,
            # the prefixes are already unique
            break

        rank = new_rank
        k *= 2

    return suffixes[1:]  # the first suffix is always the $, so we don't need it
```

Both algorithms work (on small unit tests that I wrote manually AND on large inputs they return the same results).

However, as you can see here, for an input of size 1000, nor the time complexity neither the space complexity of the efficient suffix array function are better:
[image]

I generate my large input with the following command:

```py
import random
text: str = "".join(random.choice("abn") for _ in range(1000))
```

Comment: Time complexity is much less useful than one may think. In reality something that requires say 1mln*n operations will be słower than something that requires n^2 operations, for sufficiently small n (up to 1mln in my example). Even though complexity suggests the opposite.  That's why we always measure. You probably need bigger n for the test.

Comment: Yep, literally what I realized (cf. answer I've put). I feel a bit stupid rip.

Comment: I wonder whether O(n^2 * log n) is a tight bound, i.e., whether there actually are strings where it takes time proportional to n^2 * log n. Do you know about that? Certainly not with random strings like yours, where it's rather O(n^2) for creating the suffixes and only O(n log n) for sorting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, creating the suffixes only takes O(n) right?

Comment: And sorting takes O(n^2 log(n))

Comment: Creating the suffixes creates quadratic amount of data, so of course it's not O(n) time. And comparing random strings averages O(1), not just O(n), since they highly likely differ at the beginning already. During the sort, the common prefixes get longer, but I think not enough to exceed that O(1). So sorting O(n log n) comparisons => O(n log n) time.

Comment: And in general, you ***can*** make sorting n strings take O(n² log n) time if you give all strings the same long prefix and a random short suffix. But here, the strings are suffixes of the same single string, so we don't have that freedom to create such strings. We could do something like 900 "a" followed by 100 random letters, then most suffixes would share a long common prefix, but then the suffix strings would already start sorted and the sorting would need only n-1 comparisons, so complexity would be O(n²). I don't see how to create a string where it would actually take O(n² log n).

Comment: Ohh ok that's a fair point

Comment: Just tested it, it's indeed O(n²) to create the suffixes (https://i.imgur.com/RyVwIf5.png), this is something I would've failed miserably to see if you hadn't suggested that created a quadratic amount of data cannot take O(n) time. Thank you!

Comment: Big-O complexity is for the worst case input.  You didn't test the worst case input. An input that takes O(n^2 log n) for the simple sort is N-1 `a`s, followed by a single `b`.

Comment: @MattTimmermans No, that only takes O(n^2), same reason as for my 900+100 case.

Comment: @MattTimmermans (Actually my 900+100 does take a few more comparisons, due to the random 100 chars. But yours only takes n-1.)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows After some thinking/experimenting I think I was wrong about the O(1) comparison for suffixes of a random string. I think overall it averages O(log n), making the total time for sorting the suffixes O(n log² n).

Comment: What about a string with characters in descending lexicographic order? I think it reaches the bound right?

Comment: Although no, it would realize instantly that one string is < than the other with the first character

Comment: @KellyBundy `text = "ababababababab...abz"` This should work to reach the bound. You would need to compare a significant portion of the suffix half of the time and it's not already pre-sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realised my "large inputs" were just not "large" enough.

For super duper large inputs:

[image]